# Postgresql load all values from other table which has reference

Tags: java, postgresql

I am absolutely new to PostgreSQL.

my testsetup just looks like this:

Table: userdata

```
| player_id | username  |
| --------- | ----------|
| 1         | testuser  |
```

Table Testtable 2

```
| player_id | value      |
| --------- | ---------- |
| 1         | testvalue  |
```

in userdata table, the player_id is an serial

in Testtabe 2, player_id is a reference to userdata (player_id)

How can I load the username from userdata table only using player_id in Testtable 2 with select statement?

Comment: What exactly is the result you want?

Comment: Read about [JOIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM)

Comment: **Learn SQL**. StackOverflow is *not a teaching site*. Any SQL guide will teach you about joining tables relatively quickly, since it's a core feature of SQL.

Comment: You might also try the online course offered by linkedin.  Successful completion can be added to your profile. There are lots to choose from, including basic SQL.  You'll be quite comfortable with queries if you take one of these.

Answer (score 0):

Load in both tables, and make a join between the two in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT username
FROM userdata, Testtable2
WHERE Testtable2.player_id = userdata.player_id;
```

Should return:

```
| username |
| -------- |
| testuser |
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a simple `join`?

```
select u.*, t.value
from userdata u
inner join testtable2 t using(player_id)
```

Or, if the column names may be different, with a `on` clause:

```
select u.*, t.value
from userdata u
inner join testtable2 t on t.player_id_fk = u.player_id
```